# how to count NULL categories in one SQL question

Tags: sql, null, group-by

i have a blog application were Post belongsTo Category and Category hasMany Post

Post can have a Category or not - in latter case NULL value is present in Post.category_id field.

Now i would like to have following category count with single SQL query

```
category|post_count
--------------
PHP | 2
JavaScript | 4
SomeOtherCat | 1
NULL | 3
```

The clue here is that i also want to count posts without category (NULL row above). Is it posibble with one SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  c.CategoryName,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  Posts p
    left join
  Category c
    on
      p.Category_id = c.Category_id
group by
  c.CategoryName
```

(For the purposes of group by, all NULL results go into the same group. This can be surprising to some who are only used to the fact that NULL != NULL when writing conditions)

Answer (score 0):

It should work with something like this:

```
SELECT C.category, COUNT(*) AS post_count
FROM Post P
LEFT JOIN Category C ON P.category_id=C.category_id
GROUP BY C.category
```

I'm not sure about the identity column in Category, you might need to replace with the correct name.

*Edit*: Oops - forgot the group by.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.CategoryName, Count(P.Post_ID)
FROM Category C INNER JOIN Posts P
ON P.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
GROUP BY C.CategoryName
UNION
SELECT NULL, Count(P.Post_ID)
FROM Posts P
WHERE P.CategoryID IS NULL
GROUP BY NULL
```